# Toggle partial view with AJAX

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

In my MVC-project I have this code for rendering a partial-view:

Method:

```
public ActionResult ShowArtCollection()
        {
            var model = new ViewModel();
            model.ArtWorks = db.ArtWorks.ToList();

            return PartialView("_artcollection", model);
        }
```

AJAX:

```
$("#btnArt").click(function () {

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/ShowArtCollection',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#artworks').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

I would like my `#btnArt` to be able to toggle the partial view. I mean that when the _artcollection is rendered by the click of the button, the next click should "unrender" the view. Any tips on how to achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by "unrender"? Hide, remove, do something else?

Comment: Good question, I guess hide would be the right word.

Comment: Have not really thought of it. Is an Ajax-call fetching data from a db the same thing as a simple jquery hide/show? Or can I treat it as such?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can put a flag and check if rendered next time unrender on click:

```
var rendered = false;
$("#btnArt").click(function () {

    if (!rendered) {

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/ShowArtCollection',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#artworks').html(data);
                rendered = true;
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('#artworks').html("");
        rendered = false;
    }

});
```

this will do the trick for you.